# How to store posts in MySQL database with an image reference in them

Tags: mysql, express

I'm migrating code written in php and html to new one written in ExpressJS and ReactJS (part of learning ReactJS and ExpressJS) for my website. I used to store the posts in the MySQL database as a full HTML then the PHP would pull them and parse them as follow

```html
  <p>
<span class="codeInLine">In line code as in GitHub</span> <span class="codeInLine"> 
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="name of file after removing the dashes and extension">It will show a tooltip if you hover</span> [:-4]</span>
and this is code <code>highlighted</code> with Javascript library;
</p>
```

[image]

But the problem is that is dangerous for the XSS attacks when I try to implement the same in ReactJS with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: database.html }}`.Does that mean I need to rewrite the posts in a new format?

There are also tags for the image in the database. If I were to pull the images using a function like this `<img class="StoryImage" src={storyCoverPath(botMileStone.png)} />` can the function work while being retrieved from the database?

My question in conclusion. How can I store a full post in MySQL and retrive it to a ReactJS with ExpressJS while maintaining the className and ID for the tags?

### What I tried

There was an answer suggested by other posts to save the full posts in `.md` format then read the full file using `react-markdown` library, but I can't use the class names with it